# The No. of Continuous function satisfying the condition $xf(y)+yf(x)=(x+y)f(x)f(y)$

Tags: continuity, functional-equations

Could anyone tell me?

The No. of Continuous function satisfying the condition $$xf(y)+yf(x)=(x+y)f(x)f(y)$$ is

$1,2,3,$ or  none of them?

or give me hints please.

Comment: I can think of 2: $f(x)=0$ and $f(x)=1$. They are not interesting though.

Comment: The trick usually in solving these equations is to plug in some interesting values. Otherwise you can't do much.

Comment: Related: [Find all $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$ the given equality holds: $xf(y)+yf(x)=(x+y)f(x)f(y)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/819565)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming your functions are from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$
$$
f(1)+f(1) = (1+1)f(1)f(1) \Rightarrow f(1) = 0 \text{ or } 1
$$
If $f(1) = 1$, then for any $x\neq 0$
$$
x + f(x) = (x+1)f(x) \Rightarrow f(x) = 1
$$
By continuity, $f\equiv 1$
Similarly, if $f(1) = 0$, then $f\equiv 0$.

Hence, the answer is 2.