# ¿How to solve this functional equation: $xf(y)+yf(x)=(x+y)f(x)f(y)$? Need some help!

Tags: functional-equations

So I've been reading about functional equations and how to solve them. I found a pretty interesting problem (for me) but I think I need some help, some hint. I've never worked with this kind of problems. Well, the problem is this:

Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ the following equation holds:

$$xf(y)+yf(x)=(x+y)f(x)f(y)$$

I've tried with some substitutions like $x=a$ and $y=-a$ for all $a \neq 0$  it follows that $f(a)=f(-a)$, so $f$ is an even function. After that, i realized that setting $x=y=a$ for $a \neq 0$ it follows that $\Biggl(f(a)-\frac{1}{2} \Biggr)^{2}=\frac{1}{4}$ and then $f(x)=1$ or $f(x)=0$ for all $x \neq 0$. I think I'm almost done but I still don't know that happens with $f(0)$.

I would appreciate any hint to solve this problem, ¿Could you recommend any book for this kind of exercises? , ¡Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set $x=0$ ......

Comment: Festooning your problem-statement-question with empty sentences like this does not improve anything. Voting to close as lacking context.

Comment: Some related posts: [Find all $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R$ the given equality holds: $xf(y)+yf(x)=(x+y)f(x)f(y)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/819565) and [The No. of Continuous function satisfying the condition $xf(y)+yf(x)=(x+y)f(x)f(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/478889). I found these posts [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24xf(y)%2Byf(x)%3D(x%2By)f(x)f(y)%24&p=1). For general advice on searching see: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Comment: Thanks a lot and sorry for mistakes, this is my first post :)